# How to delete an ImageField image in a Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Profile` model like so:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/users/", blank=True)
```

I want my users to be able to remove their profile pictures so that there's no image in `photo` i.e blank.

I tried `Profile.objects.get(id=1).photo.delete(save=False)` which deleted the image but the url was still there so I was getting a 404. How do I clear the image and url?

**EDIT:** In my template, I'm like:

```
{% if profile.photo %}
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ profile.photo }}" />
{% else %}
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}img/avatar.jpg" />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Show your template

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change `Profile.objects.get(id=1).photo.delete(save=False)` to `Profile.objects.get(id=1).photo.delete(save=True)`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.delete