# How to Delete a profile picture in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have created a page where a user can upload a profile picture:[![Page][1]][1]
But I also want to give the ability to remove the profile picture completly without uploading another image. That should happen when a user clicks on the button "Delete".

This is my Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from dashboard.models import Notification
from  .models import Profile

@login_required(login_url='account_login')
def dashboard_profile(request):
    n = Notification.objects.filter(user=request.user, viewed=False)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('dashboard-profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'full_name' : request.user.username,
        'notifications': n
    }
    
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='account_login')
def delete_image(DeleteView):
    #delete the image of the users Profile
    return redirect('dashboard-profile')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete an ImageField image in a Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329858/how-to-delete-an-imagefield-image-in-a-django-model)

Comment: I added `Profile.objects.get(id=1).image.delete(save=True)` and made the url-pattern `path('profile/delete/', delete_image, name = 'delete_profile'),` but it doesn`t seem to work. I just get redirected back to the profile page but the image doesn`t get deleted.

Comment: You'd have to debug that. Given that your field can't be `null`, perhaps you'll have to delete the image and add the default... I'm not sure, it needs debugging.

Comment: Ok, I made a mistake earlier but the answer worked now. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64216005/how-to-delete-a-profile-picture-in-django). Do you have an Idea on how I can also change the profile image of the user back to the default (default.png) after the old picture has been removed. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to create another function inside the `Profile` model that first deletes the old profile image and then sets the image to my default `Profile` image.

```
def SetUserImageDefault(self):
    self.user.profile.image.delete(save=False)  # delete old image file
    self.user.profile.image = 'default.png' # set default image
    self.user.profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing django-cleanup can help you

Comment: Please explain how this could solve the OP’s problem